# No property found SpringBoot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

I encouter this error while running the app, i dont understand why.. i found information on the web, but can't understand what's wrong. Thanks for help.

2 ) Another question regarding this, should i put :

```
List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByIdNamespaceAndIdService(Namespace id_namespace, Service id_service);
Or
List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByIdNamespaceAndIdService(Integer id_namespace, Integer id_service);
```

The error :

```
Error creating bean with name 'checkConfigDeploiementRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.jpa.repository.CheckConfigDeploiementRepository.findByIdNamespaceAndIdService(com.example.jpa.model.Namespace,com.example.jpa.model.Service)! No property namespace found for type Integer! Traversed path: CheckConfigDeploiement.id.
```

The Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "historiquedeploiement")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HistoriqueDeploiement extends AuditModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private Integer id;    

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_namespace", nullable = false)    
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    @JsonProperty("id_namespace")
    private Namespace namespace;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_service", nullable = false)    
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    @JsonProperty("id_service")
    private Service service;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Le GitCommit ne peut être vide")
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String gitCommit;   
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Le TagVersion ne peut être vide")
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String tagVersion;  
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "Le Actionby ne peut être vide")
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String actionBy;    
    
}
```

NamespaceEntity ( same with service..)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "namespace")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Namespace extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String namespace;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "namespace", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)  
    private List<HistoriqueDeploiement> historiquedeploiements = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addHistoriqueDeploiement(HistoriqueDeploiement historiquedeploiement) {
        historiquedeploiements.add(historiquedeploiement);
        historiquedeploiement.setNamespace(this);
    }

    public void removeHistoriqueDeploiement(HistoriqueDeploiement historiquedeploiement) {
        historiquedeploiements.remove(historiquedeploiement);
        historiquedeploiement.setNamespace(null);
    }
}
```

The repo, i don't understand what i'm doing wrong :

```
...
@Repository
public interface HistoriqueDeploiementRepository extends JpaRepository<HistoriqueDeploiement, Integer> {        
    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findAll();
    
    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByIdNamespace(Integer id);
    
    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByIdNamespaceAndIdService(Namespace id_namespace, Service id_service);
    
    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByIdNamespaceAndLogCreatedAtBetween(Namespace id_namespace, Date datedebut, Date datefin);

    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByIdNamespaceAndLogCreatedAt(Namespace id_namespace, Date date);

}
```

Comment: Would you mind please writing out a SQL query which you would like the repository method to execute? Namely it seems to me that you would like a list of HistoriqueDeploiement entities, such that the related namespaces and services have some properties. If this truly is the case, then you need some joins, and it is unlikely that you will be able to make that happen with Spring Data DSL

Comment: I use mapping and DTO to get the value that i need (i understand what you say).
But actually the problem is with my repo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I looked at your problem and here is what I found. The types you assigned to your repository interface method parameters are wrong.

You are looking to obtain a list of HistoriqueDeploiement entities whose Namespace and Service entities have specific IDs. Note that IDs of Namespace and Service entities are Integer types. So in order to solve you can simply rewrite your methods as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface HistoriqueDeploiementRepository extends 
JpaRepository<HistoriqueDeploiement, Integer> {        
    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findAll();

    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByNamespaceId(Integer id);

    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByNamespaceIdAndServiceId(Integer id_namespace, Integer id_service);

    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByNamespaceIdAndLogCreatedAtBetween(Integer id_namespace, Date datedebut, Date datefin);

    List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByNamespaceIdAndLogCreatedAt(Integer id_namespace, Date date);
}
```

Note that major change here is that we replaced Namespace and Service types with Integer type, which is the actual type of their IDs

Comment: It was my first test, but with that i have : `No property namespace found for type Integer`

Comment: Hastingly I have forgot to make changes to method names, but only did the parameters. I have edited my answer and now it should work

Comment: App is running with that, but i don't understand why `NamespaceId` and not IdNamespace ?? Thanks !

Comment: If you had instance of Namespace named namespace how would you access its id attribute ? You would use namespace.getId(), but since method names can not contain dots and braces, then the convention was to write it as NamespaceId